# In inheritance are there cases where all the types of heirs get a share?

Tags: fiqh, inheritance

In the inheritance according to the islamic jurisprudence we have quota heirs ذوي الفروض which get a known amount of the share and residuary who may get from what is available after the all the quota heirs got their share. These heirs basically fall under the kinds spouses or parents or children or siblings

My question is is or are there any case(s) in which all kinds of heirs get a part?

To make it clearer: what I mean is are there any cases where it is possible that

- a spouse
- at least a parent
- at least one child
- at least one sibling

would inherit as it seems that there are cases where some of the possible heirs don't get any share, because others have primacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the answer to your related question [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/52955/20218). A spouse, parent and child will always receive a share. A sibling may get a share in the absence of a male parent or child, according to the school of thought. So in the following case each of the listed heirs will receive a share: Spouse, Mother, Daughter, Sibling, provided that the father is not alive and there are no sons.